InvalidAccountData error on token transfer function ( using metaplex-toolbox )
I've created a dApp on React which uses the Solana blockchain to create, mint, and send utility tokens. I'm using @metaplex-foundation/umi and @mpl-toolbox to create the token, mint it to the creator's account, and then send the created tokens to any wallet address. Now, the token creation ( using createFungibleAsset instruction ) and the token minting (using mintV1) are working perfectly fine. When I use the transferToken instruction, the instruction fails with this error:

Program returned error: "invalid account data for instruction"

Also, the instruction works perfectly for the account to which the tokens were minted ( also being the creator account ) but fails for the accounts with no ATA. I've even tried creating an ATA for these accounts but still, the transaction fails.
Here's the relevant part of the code:
const [mint, setMint] = useState(generateSigner(umi));

// function triggered when the 'Create Token' button is clicked
  const submitHandler = async () => {
    const tokenName = tokenNameRef.current?.value || "";
    const tokenSymbol = tokenSymbolRef.current?.value || "";
    const tokenDescription = tokenDescriptionRef.current?.value || "";

    console.log(tokenName, tokenSymbol, tokenDescription);

    const mint = generateSigner(umi);
    setMint(mint);
    const tokenMetadata = {
      tokenName,
      tokenSymbol,
      tokenDescription,
    };

    // upload the tokenMetadata to irys ( previously bundlr)
    const uri = await umi.uploader.uploadJson([tokenMetadata]);

    console.log("TokenMetadata uploaded successfully", uri);
    toast.success("Token metadata uploaded successfully");

    // create the fungible token

    createFungibleAsset(umi, {
      mint,
      name: tokenMetadata.tokenName,
      symbol: tokenMetadata.tokenSymbol,
      uri: uri,
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0),
      isMutable: true,
      isCollection: false,
      authority: umi.identity, // the address which is allowed to mint the tokens
      decimals: 3, // the divisibility of the fungible token
    })
      .sendAndConfirm(umi)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(
          tokenMetadata.tokenName + "created successfully: ",
          mint.publicKey
        );
        toast.success(" Token created successfully!");
        setCanMintTokens(true);
      });
  };

// Minting the fungible token using the mpl-token-metadata library's mintV1 function
  const mintHandler = () => {
    const tokensToMint = mintAmountRef.current?.value || 0;
    mintV1(umi, {
      mint: mint.publicKey,
      authority: umi.identity,
      amount: +tokensToMint * 1000,
      tokenOwner: umi.identity.publicKey,
      tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
    })
      .sendAndConfirm(umi, { send: { skipPreflight: true } }) // preflight is Solana's simulation of the txn, if simulation fails, txn is failed and not even sent to the chains
      .then(() => {
        console.log("minted successfully!");
        toast.success(" Token minted successfully!");
      });
  };

// Send SPL tokens
  const sendSplTokensHandler = async () => {
    const tokenAmount = Number(numOfTokensToSendRef.current?.value) || 0;

    if (!destinationWalletAddressRef.current?.value) {
      throw new Error("Please provide a destination wallet address.");
    }

    if (!wallet || !wallet.publicKey) {
      throw new Error("Wallet not loaded");
    }

    if (tokenAmount <= 0) {
      throw new Error("Token amount must be greater than 0.");
    }
    const destinationWalletAddress = publicKey(
      destinationWalletAddressRef.current?.value
    );

    const senderTokenAccount = findAssociatedTokenPda(umi, {
      // Gets the ATA of the sender account
      mint: mint.publicKey,
      owner: umi.payer.publicKey,
    });
    const receiverTokenAccount = findAssociatedTokenPda(umi, {
      // Predicts the ATA of the recepient acc which doesn't exist yet
      mint: mint.publicKey,
      owner: destinationWalletAddress,
    });

    let txnBuilder = transactionBuilder();

    txnBuilder = txnBuilder.add(
      createTokenIfMissing(umi, {
        // creates the recipient ATA
        mint: mint.publicKey,
        // token: receiverTokenAccount,
        // ata: receiverTokenAccount,
        owner: receiverTokenAccount,
      })
    );

    txnBuilder = txnBuilder.append(
      transferTokens(umi, {
        source: senderTokenAccount,
        destination: receiverTokenAccount,
        amount: tokenAmount,
      })
    );
    txnBuilder
      .sendAndConfirm(umi, { send: { skipPreflight: true } })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Token sent");
        toast.success("Token sent");
      });
  };

Now, I'll attach the transaction failure screenshot:

I'll also attach the Solana Explorer link:
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3pen4jY2EJWFM7fQz2wZ7PcymyT45Dq6YqJMnqZ125bSedzxud4keYHauo7ewpZ1JbKeVCsXfuVXWjuX7Kju4gJv?cluster=devnet

If you look at the last failing instruction in your transaction, you'll notice that it's issuing a transfer from HCBDHVQTrfMVvQEQwowE6dFj6JqKM3U4aGeac1hukyYi to EFKaPHLSxG8mCnDKMWzH9vWakNRAJeCs5NFgStsRUbNB. The first account looks correct https://explorer.solana.com/address/HCBDHVQTrfMVvQEQwowE6dFj6JqKM3U4aGeac1hukyYi?cluster=devnet, but the second one doesn't exist https://explorer.solana.com/address/EFKaPHLSxG8mCnDKMWzH9vWakNRAJeCs5NFgStsRUbNB?cluster=devnet.
Be sure to create the token account at EFKaPHLSxG8mCnDKMWzH9vWakNRAJeCs5NFgStsRUbNB before attempting a transfer using something like getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.
There's likely something wrong in createTokenIfMissing since it's not creating the account.
